# Проверка изображения при загрузке

Tags: php, изображения, сервер

В общем, на сервер загружается изображение следующим образом:

Юзер выбирает изображение на локальном ПК -> файл грузится в tmp, там проверяется размер, тип файла и тд.

Единственное, тчо нужно добавить  - определение размера изображение, и если оно больше, чем  90х90 - обрезать его до этого значения, либо ужать.

Какие примеры реализации есть для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в PHP есть встроенная вещь, называется `getimagesize`, она вернет тебе массив, где [0] - ширина, [1] - высота. А для уменьшения размеров, лучше загуглите библиотеку для работы с картинками (их полным полно) и так проще будет.

Comment: > в PHP есть встроенная вещь

расширение php-gd вообще-то